# How to render the wiki markup obtained using MediaWiki in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markup, wikipedia-api, wikitext

I have a page which uses the [MediaWiki gem](https://github.com/kenpratt/wikipedia-client) to extract wiki details and show it to the user. The user enters what they want to search for and then using MediaWiki gem I fetch the data and image.

I am able to show the images but unable to render the data as it's in wiki markup.

So what should I use? I googled and think that the redcloth gem can help me out. Should I try it or there are any other gems/logic that I am missing?

Below is the code that I am using:

**my gemfile..**

```
gem 'mediawiki-gateway'
gem 'wikipedia-client'
gem 'wikitext', '~> 2.1.1'
# gem 'red-cloth'
```

**my controller..**

```
  require 'media_wiki'
  require 'wikipedia'

   @page = Wikipedia.find('BMW')
   #using this parser ..should i change this>??
   @page=Wikitext::Parser.new.parse(@page.content)
```

**my view file**

```
<h1><%= @page.title%></h1>

<div id="image_container">  
    <% @page.image_urls[1..3].each do |image| %>


    <%= image_tag(image) %>
    <% end %>
</div>

<div id="content_class">

    <%=h @page.html_safe %>
</div>
<!-- purposely usign html safe as without it the view looks really bad(atleast now i can see the links highlighted in blue color) -->
```

**A quick view of what my problem is---please refer the attached image[image]**

**I want to improve the UI. How can i do it?**

Comment: Are you sure that the wikitext parser works with that syntax? Did you try one of those libraries? http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers

Comment: MediaWiki API can parse the markup for you. Doesn't the library let you do that?

Comment: @phoet That still won't help with parsing templates.

Comment: @svick I have no clue. The wikitext docs just had examples in a different syntax style.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't parse wikitext yourself. The [TextExtracts](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:TextExtracts) and [PageImages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageImages) web APIs exist for a reason. There's plenty of [web API client libraries](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code) too.